# Buscar en 2 campos distintos de un array de objetos a partir de otro array

Tags: array, typescript

Tengo un array simple:

```
array = ['campo1','campo2']
```

Y aquí el otro:

```
array2 = [
   {'campo1': x},
   {'campo2': x},
   {'campo3': x},
]
```

En un input he de introducir texto y que lo busque en cualquier campo del array2

Me funciona así:

```
this.array2.filter((option: any) => 
 (option[this.array[0]].toLowerCase().includes('textoIntroducidoEnUnInput')) ||
 (option[this.array[1]].toLowerCase().includes('textoIntroducidoEnUnInput')));
```

El problema es que yo no sé cuántos campos son ni como se llaman, ¿cómo haríais la búsqueda en los 2 campos y que lo devuelva todo en un mismo array? Lo he intentado con un for pero sólo devuelve los casos en los que el texto introducido coincida en todos los campos

Comment: Entiendo que la búsqueda ya no estaría atada al primer `array`. Es sólo una búsqueda en el segundo `array`. ¿O me equivoco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `reduce` dentro de `filter`, para comprobar si se encuentra alguno de los campos con el valor esperado:

```js
const campos = ['campo1','campo2'];


const array2 = [
   {'campo1': 'A'},
   {'campo2': 'B'},
   {'campo3': 'A'},
   {'campo2': 'A'},
   {'campo1': 'B','campo2': 'A'},
];


function buscaCampos(campos,array, value) {
  return array.filter(obj => { //comprobamos para cada objeto
    return campos.reduce((resultado,campo) => {
      //si tiene alguno de los campos con el valor esperado
      return resultado || (obj[campo] && obj[campo].toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase()); 
    },false);
  });
}

const input = document.querySelector('input');
const pre = document.querySelector('pre');
input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(buscaCampos(campos,array2, input.value), null, 2);
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="Escribe A o B"/>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto. Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda!!!